# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in php. Couldn't find where did i do wrong?

Tags: php

I got an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in        C:\xampp\htdocs\Web_app\nav.php on line 26

With this code

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar">`
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    $_SESSION['client_id'] ='1';
>if client is not logged in
    //client login
    <?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['client_id']))
    { 
     ?>
    <li><a href="#"> Login</a></li>
    <?php} 

       else{?>
    <li><a href="#"> Edit Account </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> My Account </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> log out</a></li>
    <?php}?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

I have configured the php.ini file but still can't solve the problem. Is there any syntax related problem?

Comment: is it have any realtion with css?

Comment: You have not closed php tag properly the `?>` tag

Comment: add full code..

Comment: Yes it have relations with css..I have added the full code

Comment: This is your actual code? `$_SESSION['client_id'] ='1';` is not in PHP...

Comment: I would suggest getting a php aware code editor/ide, it will help suss out the syntax errors in this code.

Comment: i am using brackets. Can you suggest one?

Answer (score 0):

You can write  **$_SESSION['client_id'] ='1';**  this inside php tag not and add white space in

Comment: The current code doesn't seem like it'd throw a parser error. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need whitespace after `<?php` for it to be recognized properly. So change

```
<?php}
```

to

```
<?php }
```

Also, the assignment

```
$_SESSION['client_id'] = '1';
```

needs to be inside `<?php ... ?>`, not in the HTML section.

Comment: Solved it. Thank You very much for the assist